# I want to create custom arc shape button

Tags: android

I want to create a back and save button that look like the buttons in the image below. I tried but i did not find any solution. I do not want to use an image as a button. Please help me..

Here is the image of back and save button..

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with using an ImageButton?

Comment: I will have to use it many times

Comment: I still don't see the problem. If you save it in a moderate format it shouldn't be that much slower than a shape.